# Why do I have to use SetProperty in all properties in Xamarin code?

Tags: xamarin, properties, getter-setter

I am new to Xamarin. I am working on an existing codebase with lots of pages and viewmodels. It seems to be a standard in Xamarin to always have a private variable with every public property in a view model, and to always call SetProperty in the setter. Like this:

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _myProperty, value); }
}
```

What does SetProperty do? Do I need to do this for every single property, or only some? What happens if I just use a simple property with default getters and setters? Like this:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

My guess is that it does something to do with the binding to the XAML files, and is necessary if you want your views to update when these properties are changed. But I have not seen this explained anywhere.

Comment: _"What does `SetProperty` do?"_ - it's an inherited method that raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event, so consumers of your ViewModel (i.e. your XAML bindings) can update themselves automatically (note this doesn't happen synchronously, instead the event is managed by the current `Dispatcher`, so invoking a property-setter twice won't necessarily mean the UI is updated twice.

Comment: BTW, I don't know if Xamarin's `SetProperty` performs "has-actually-changed?" checks for you or not (and if it does, it almost certainly would depend on some default equality behaviour), so if you need a custom equality comparison just-for-this-single-property (rather than in general) you should add your own guard `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't **have to** use this.  But this mechanism, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, is what drives the data binding mechanism used by Xamarin Forms (and other Microsoft UI stacks).  `SetProperty` basically raises an event notifying the UI that a property has changed, and if the UI is displaying that property, that it needs to refresh.

note that this

```
public string MyProperty;
```

is **NOT** a C# property.  It's just a `field`.  A `property` needs a `get` and/or `set`.  Data binding **only** works with **public properties**.

Google `INotifyPropertyChanged` for many extensive writeups on how this interface works and how to best implement it.

A wonderful nuget package exists, [Fody PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), that will automate much of the boilerplate code involved in using INPC.  It works great with Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Ugh, my mistake, you are of course completely correct, I will update my question with a real C# property.

Comment: That Fody thing is interesting, I'll have to look into using that later.

Comment: @Nacht [There are some gotchas with Fody, though](https://bytelanguage.net/2021/02/11/fody-and-onpropertychanged-the-unusual-behavior/), not to mention you can’t step-through-debug Fody’s generated code (at least last time I checked). An alternative to Fody is to use T4 to do codegen at design-time (or build-time) into a `partial` type, which can be fully debugged. Another alternative is Roslyn build-time code-generation, but you can’t make spot-changes to Roslyn codegen output like we can with T4.